# Multiple Inner Joins from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Setting up a single inner join from two tables is quite straightforward, code below.

```
SELECT A.[Col1], A.[Col2], A.[Col3], A.[Col4], B.[ColJ], B.[ColK] 
  FROM Table_A AS A
    INNER JOIN Table_B AS B
    ON A.[Col1] = B.[ColJ]
```

However, table in question is quite complex and will require multiple joins. Something like this:

```
SELECT A.[Col1], A.[Col2], A.[Col3], A.[Col4], B.[ColJ], B.[ColK] 
  FROM Table_A AS A
    INNER JOIN Table_B AS B
    ON A.[Col1] = B.[ColJ]
    INNER JOIN Table_B AS C
    ON A.[Col2] = C.[ColK]
```

But I am unable to make it work.

Any advise?

Thanks

**EDIT**

My actual code:

```
SELECT
  j.[AA Number]
  ,j.[AA Role]
  ,j.[Project Name] AS [j Project Name]
  ,j.Series AS [j Series]
  ,j.[Paper No]
  ,j.[Task Name] AS [j Task Name]
  ,j.Amount
  ,a.[Project Name] AS [TEP_Projects_Tasks_Full Project Name]
  ,a.[Project Number]
  ,a.[Task Name] AS [TEP_Projects_Tasks_Full Task Name]
  ,a.[Expenditure Organization]
FROM
  TEP_Payments_Table as j
  inner JOIN TEP_Projects_Tasks_Full as a
    ON j.[Project Name] = a.[Project Name]
  inner join TEP_Projects_Tasks_Full as b
    on j.[Task Name] = b.[Task Name]
```

Results I get looks like this:

[image]

As you can see - Task Name was not joined properly, it is returning all Task Names, rather than the correct one, in this instance, Sampling..

If I use a instead of b (As per comment below) I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Yes you can.. have you tried to run your query like you have written above?

Comment: @Harry of course... but do not get expected results..

Comment: would help if you show some data and desired results.. it maybe that you need outer joins.. but technically.. the join you have specified is valid

Comment: I will edit question

Comment: @D-Shih see edit

Comment: Why did you need to `inner join TEP_Projects_Tasks_Full as b` even you didn't use `b`

Comment: Because if I use a, I get error. See screenshot above.

Comment: @OdaySalim I answered a question

Comment: If you are getting all possible task names that could be because you have a task name that is NULL.  There are a ton of potential issues with this and it is probably that your joins are not correct.  The best way to get help on a question like this to actually post table schema, example data and expected result and try to explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to select `b.[Task Name] AS [TEP_Projects_Tasks_Full Task Name]` instead of `a.[Task Name] AS [TEP_Projects_Tasks_Full Task Name]`

```
SELECT
  j.[AA Number]
  ,j.[AA Role]
  ,j.[Project Name] AS [j Project Name]
  ,j.Series AS [j Series]
  ,j.[Paper No]
  ,j.[Task Name] AS [j Task Name]
  ,j.Amount
  ,a.[Project Name] AS [TEP_Projects_Tasks_Full Project Name]
  ,a.[Project Number]
  ,b.[Task Name] AS [TEP_Projects_Tasks_Full Task Name]
  ,a.[Expenditure Organization]
FROM
  TEP_Payments_Table as j
  inner JOIN TEP_Projects_Tasks_Full as a
    ON j.[Project Name] = a.[Project Name]
  inner join TEP_Projects_Tasks_Full as b
    on j.[Task Name] = b.[Task Name]
```